# Laravel Eloquent - Prevent returning specific columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have a table `Client` and this has some columns. I specifically do not want to send back a few of the columns in the this table when a call is made to the model.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do literally what you asked for. `hidden` and `visible` properties are the ones to check when you want to limit properties printed on a model (with `toJson`/`toArray` methods)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh it's really simple, just add

```
protected $hidden = array('password');
```

to your model class! Check out the docs for more info! http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent